# Django not logging in properly when custom backend and models are used

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication backend in Django but its behaving in a very strange way. The custom backend authenticate against a different model from the usual Django User model an upon successfully verifying the provided credentials the backend get or create our usual Django User instance which it returns. Login nevertheless doesn't work.

From the documentation I learnt that I just needed to inherit the `django.contrib.auth.backends.BaseBackend` and override the `authenticate()` method which I did. As I've mentioned the custom `authenticate()` method basically verifies a set of credentials (username and password) against ones stored in the database (custom model, not `django.contrib.auth.models.User`) which if matched it would get or create an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` via a proxy model which I named `Profile`; basically the `Profile` model has a reference of both `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and my custom model. When logging in though I keep redirected to the login page (It's like Django logs me in but doesn't set something somewhere such that when I try accessing a protected resource I'm redirected back to login). Also when I login which a `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object it works just fine and I can access the protected pages. Following are the reasons I opted for this authentication approach.

1. I'm working with an existing database that has it's own User tables with very different schema than what Django provides.(Actually the only fields in this system User table similar to Django's are username, and password)
2. I utilized Django's `inspectb` management command to recreate the models of which I'm under strict instructions to leave unmanaged, you know, `manage=False` in the model's `meta class`. Basically I can't inherit Django's `AbstractUser` as it would require new fields to be added.

Thus the best approach I could think of was to use a proxy model that would link both `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and my custom unmanaged models with a custom Authentication Backend.
I've tried watching for certain variables such as the `request.session` dictionary and `request.user` all which are set but still can't login successfully. Also when I use credentials that are not in either of the two models I get a `Invalid Credentials` message in the login page (desirable behavior).
Actually, my custom `authenticate()` method works fine and returns a valid user, the issue I think lies in `django.contrib.auth.login`. What could be the problem?

Here is the my `authenticate` method

```
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            c_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
            
        #pwd_valid = check_password(password, user.password)
        if not c_user.password==password:
            return None
        
        #Get and return the django user object
        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(custom_user=c_user)
            user = profile.user
            #Create user if profile has none
            if not user:
                user = User.objects.create(
                    username=''.join(secrets.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(24))
                )
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
        #Create new profile if none exists        
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            #Create new user for the profile    
            user = User.objects.create(
                username=''.join(secrets.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(24))
            )    
              
            Profile.objects.create(
                user = user,
                custom_user = c_user
            )
        return user
```

Here is how I added the custom backend to settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'Authentication.custom.CustomAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe I'm answering my own question. After much debugging and reading documentation I realized I didn't override `get_user` method of the `django.contrib.auth.backends.BaseBackend` thus the default one which returns `None` was always called. I implemented it and it worked like a charm.